# import/ upload file Using Drag and Drop In MAUI

Tags: macos, maui

I am encountering an issue while attempting to import a file using the drag and drop feature in MAUI.

Although there are several known bugs in MAUI, a few developers have provided solutions for Windows and Mac platforms.

Here are the solutions:

1. https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6080#issuecomment-1617305358
2. https://vladislavantonyuk.github.io/articles/Drag-and-Drop-any-content-to-a-.NET-MAUI-application/

Both solutions offer a similar approach, which I have used to create a sample application. In the sample app, I found that using a `ScrollView, AbsoluteLayout, or StackLayout` works fine. However, when attempting to use a `CollectionView` on a Mac machine, it doesn't function properly.

If anyone has a solution for this issue, please provide your input.
Solution Created By me:

https://github.com/theRealGupta/MAUI-FileDragAndDrop

Comment: Relevant code needs to be included in your post, not linked as an offsite repo

Comment: As far as the current situation is concerned, you can continue to pay attention to that issue to see if there is any update.